# I Try to insert two tables using multi query in pdo but it gives this Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::multi_query()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I try to insert using multi query it gives error, but without multi query it inserts the first table only and the second table doesn't get any data.Here Is My Code

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'root';
$db_pass        = '';
$db_database    = 'rambo'; 

$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_database, $db_user, $db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $a = $_POST['invoice'];
    $b = $_POST['id_ya_dawa'];
    //$c = $_POST['idadi_zilizotoka'];
    $w = $_POST['re_id'];
    $x = $_POST['customer'];
    $u = $_POST['CreatedBy'];
    $t = $_POST['insurance'];
    $s = $_POST['strengthtype'];
    $n = $_POST['dosage'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $l = $_POST['ApprovalRefNo'];
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id= :userid");
    $result->bindParam(':userid', $b);
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
      $asasa=$row['UnitPrice'];
      $gen=$row['gen_name'];
      $code=$row['ItemCode'];
    $p=$row['profit'];
    }
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO solditem (invoice,id_ya_dawa,name,package,re_id,customer,CreatedBy,insurance,strengthtype,dosage,age,ItemCode,UnitPrice,ApprovalRefNo,DateCreated) VALUES (:a,:b,:e,:i,:w,:x,:u,:t,:s,:n,:v,:p,:r,:l,NOW());";
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO anotheritem (DateCreated,CreatedBy,UnitPrice,LastModified,LastModifiedBy,ItemName,ItemCode,ApprovalRefNo,re_id) VALUES (NOW(),:w,:u,:p,NOW(),:w,:e,:v,:r,:l)";
    
    $q =$db -> multi_query($sql);
    $q =$db -> next_result();
    $q->execute(array(':a'=>$a,':b'=>$b,':e'=>$gen,':i'=>$code,':w'=>$w,':x'=>$x,':u'=>$u,':t'=>$t,':s'=>$s,':n'=>$n,':v'=>$age,':p'=>$asasa,':r'=>$code,':l'=>$l));
    header("location: resale.php?re_id=$w&invoice=$a");
    
    
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`multi_query` and `next_result` are functions in MySQLi, not PDO.

Change

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO solditem (invoice,id_ya_dawa,name,package,re_id,customer,CreatedBy,insurance,strengthtype,dosage,age,ItemCode,UnitPrice,ApprovalRefNo,DateCreated) VALUES (:a,:b,:e,:i,:w,:x,:u,:t,:s,:n,:v,:p,:r,:l,NOW());";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO anotheritem (DateCreated,CreatedBy,UnitPrice,LastModified,LastModifiedBy,ItemName,ItemCode,ApprovalRefNo,re_id) VALUES (NOW(),:w,:u,:p,NOW(),:w,:e,:v,:r,:l)";
$q =$db -> multi_query($sql);
$q =$db -> next_result();
$q->execute (array(':a'=>$a,':b'=>$b,':e'=>$gen,':i'=>$code,':w'=>$w,':x'=>$x,':u'=>$u,':t'=>$t,':s'=>$s,':n'=>$n,':v'=>$age,':p'=>$asasa,':r'=>$code,':l'=>$l));
```

to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO solditem (invoice,id_ya_dawa,name,package,re_id,customer,CreatedBy,insurance,strengthtype,dosage,age,ItemCode,UnitPrice,ApprovalRefNo,DateCreated) VALUES (:a,:b,:e,:i,:w,:x,:u,:t,:s,:n,:v,:p,:r,:l,NOW());";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':a'=>$a,':b'=>$b,':e'=>$gen,':i'=>$code,':w'=>$w,':x'=>$x,':u'=>$u,':t'=>$t,':s'=>$s,':n'=>$n,':v'=>$age,':p'=>$asasa,':r'=>$code,':l'=>$l));
$sql = "INSERT INTO anotheritem (DateCreated,CreatedBy,UnitPrice,LastModified,LastModifiedBy,ItemName,ItemCode,ApprovalRefNo,re_id) VALUES (NOW(),:w,:u,:p,NOW(),:w,:e,:v,:r,:l)";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':w'=>$w,':u'=>$u,':p'=>$asasa,':e'=>$gen,':v'=>$age,':r'=>$code,':l'=>$l));
```